# Finding certain improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I need to find two functions,
$f, g : (0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, such that both integrals $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx $ and  $\int_{0}^{1} g(x) dx $ are improper and exist but the product is an improper integral $f(x).g(x)$ which does not exist.

My problem is I can only think of one function whose integral would be improper in (0,1] and which would exist, that would be ln(x).

Could someone tell me a second function which would fulfill this and also that $f(x) g(x)$ doesn‘t exist anymore?

Comment: Consider $f$ and $g$ same.

Comment: $f(x) = g(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\sin x}}{x}$

Comment: more simply $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ ..

Comment: thank you both so much!